# GPA calculator crash bug in c++

Tags: c++

I am a noob in programming and was told that to learn more, I need to do some project and so I started this GPA calculator that eventually prints your GPS in both 5 unit and it 4 unit equivalent.

The problem is I created an array to hold the grade point from A-F and another array to hold the letter grade from 0-5, but after I was done it performed well until I noticed it crashes when I try to calculate for more than 6 courses, I have tried what I can do but still can't detect the bug and solve the problem all to no avail.

```
    #include<iomanip>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){
            int numOfCourse;

            cout<<"insert the number of courses offered: ";
            cin>>numOfCourse;

            int scores[numOfCourse];//an array that stores the number of course inputed by the user
            int creditUnit[numOfCourse];//another array that stores the credit unit of the user
            int qualityPoint[numOfCourse];//this is gotten by multiplying the credit unit by grade point
            int totalQualityPoint=0;
            int totalCreditUnit=0;
            int gradePoint[6];//predefined grade point 0-5
            string letterGrade[6];//predefined letter grade A-F which corresponds with the grade point
            float gradePointAverage5;//5 point GPA Scale
            float gradePointAverage4;// 4 point GPA Scale

    // Asks the user to input scores and credit load of the courses
        for (int i=0; i< numOfCourse; i++){
            cout<<"input the scores of the course: "; 
            cin>>scores[i];
            cout<<" input the credit load of the course: ";
            cin>>creditUnit[i];


    //defining the gradepoint and its corresponding letter grade
        if(scores[i] <= 39){
            gradePoint[i]=0;
            letterGrade[i] = "F";       
        } else if (scores[i] >=40 && scores[i] <= 44){
            gradePoint[i]=1;
            letterGrade[i] ="E";
        } else if (scores[i] >=45 &&scores[i]<= 49){
            gradePoint[i]=2;
            letterGrade[i] = "D";
        }else if (scores[i] >=50 &&scores[i] <= 59){
            gradePoint[i] =3;
            letterGrade[i] = "C";
        }else if (scores[i] >=60 &&scores[i] <= 69){
            gradePoint[i]=4;
            letterGrade[i] = "B";
        }else if (scores[i]>=69 &&scores[i] <= 100){
            gradePoint[i]=5;
            letterGrade[i] = "A";
        }else{
            cout<< "Your grade is incorrect"<<endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }


cout<<"Scores       Letter      Credit      Grade       QualityPoint"<<endl;
        cout<<"     Grade       Unit        Point       (CU * GP)"<<endl;


for(int i =0; i<numOfCourse;i++){
    qualityPoint[i] = creditUnit[i] *  gradePoint[i];

cout<<scores[i] <<"     "<<letterGrade[i]<<"        "<<creditUnit[i]
<<"     "<<gradePoint[i]<< "        "<<qualityPoint[i]<<endl;

totalQualityPoint=totalQualityPoint + qualityPoint[i];
totalCreditUnit=totalCreditUnit + creditUnit[i];
gradePointAverage5= float(totalQualityPoint)/float(totalCreditUnit);
gradePointAverage4 = (gradePointAverage5/5)*4;
} 

    cout<< "Your total Quality Point is: "<<totalQualityPoint<<endl;
    cout<< "Your total Credit Unit is: "<<totalCreditUnit<<endl;
    cout<< "Your Grade Point Average (GPA) on the 5 point scale is : "<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<gradePointAverage5<<endl;
    cout<< "Your Grade Point Average (GPA) on the 4 point scale is : "<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<gradePointAverage4<<endl;

    }
```

Comment: You've defined `gradePoint` and `letterGrade` to be only 6 in size, but access them with `i` which is more than 6 when your program breaks.

Comment: I don't like the VLA usage however that is not the issue.

Comment: `int scores[numOfCourse];` -- This isn't valid C++.  C++ requires arrays to have compile-time constants to declare the number of entries, not a variable.  Use `std::vector<int> scores(numOfCourse);` instead.

Comment: This is why you really must learn to use the debugger. One of Its jobs is to show you where (and usually why) you crashed.